# Set date to 31.12. automatically with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following DATES_TABLE(id, start_date, duration_period). I need to remove the duration period and have the end date as a field.

I am using the following script to update the end date:

```
alter table DATES_TABLE add END_DATE date;

update DATES_TABLE
SET END_DATE = add_months (START_DATE, DURATION_PERIOD * 12);
```

If the start date was 01.01.2018 and projection duration was 10, then the end date will be set to 01.01.2028. This is correct, but the end date needs to set to the last day in the year, meaning 31.12.2028. In all cases, the year should change, but the day should be 31 and the month December.

How can I do this in sql?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get the rules you are using.  What happens if you are adding 9 months?  What if the start date is Jan 2?  Jan 30?

Comment: See the `end_date` as not included in the period (period is all times >= `start_date` and **<** `end_date`). That's the correct way anyway, to fully include the last day regardless of how precise the time is (seconds, milliseconds, nano seconds, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update DATES_TABLE
   SET END_DATE =
       trunc(
           add_months(
               add_months (START_DATE, DURATION_PERIOD * 12),
               12),
           'YYYY')
        - 1;
```

Watch out with this date, there's a whole day left in the same year after 31/12/NNNN 00:00:00.  If you want to cater for that, just subtract one second iso. one day.

As Elyor pointed out, I was still wasting some cpu cycles there.

```
update DATES_TABLE
   SET END_DATE =
       trunc(
           add_months (START_DATE, (DURATION_PERIOD + 1) * 12),
           'YYYY')
        - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you may need something like the following:

```
update dates_table
set end_date = to_date('31-12-' || extract(year from add_months(start_date, duration_period *12)), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: Try both and time them.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update testdate
SET END_DATE = add_months (trunc(START_DATE,'y'),12)-1;
```